# Where is the UTC timezone in CentOS?

Tags: centos, timezone

I was running the CentOS installer, and was surprised that I couldn't find `UTC` when prompted for the timezone.

The only available choices are:

- Etc/GMT
- Etc/GMT±[1-12]
- Etc/UTC

However, I recently learned that [Etc/UTC is not the same as UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128574/is-there-a-difference-between-the-utc-and-etc-utc-time-zones).

So why is only `Etc/UTC` proposed and not `UTC`?

Comment: Can't you use `TZ='UTC-0'` which is a posix compatible TZ format in your `/etc/profile` (after installation of course)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [IANA's time zone database](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/data/etcetera), `Etc/UTC` is the specifier for the timezone whose display name is `UTC` -- that is, it's UTC. So the premise of your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 12):

You should see a list of possible timezones in

```
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

at the top level should be `UTC`. To change the timezone of the server, you need to change (or set) the symbolic link `/etc/localtime` (after you found the location of UTC in *zoneinfo* directory above)

```
rm -f /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

[more info](http://centminmod.com/datetimezones.html)

Comment: Thanks for this info. Any idea why it's not proposed during installation, then?

Comment: On my system `UTC` is at the top - my guess is that 'etc' means the same as in '/etc' i.e. 'etcetera' (since UTC is not part of a continent, they had to put it somewhere if not at the top, *etc* sounds like a good destination on a Unix based system)

Answer (score 0):

When installing CentOS you can select the Etc category then under city just scroll to the top and you'll see Coordinated Universal Time. This wasn't so obvious as a choice, seems like UTC should be a direct option under Region.